# How can I use arrays from main for a swing graph?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans, program-entry-point

i have a java class, main, in net beans, where i calculate 10000 or 10000000 double values, and i store them in x[] and y[] . 
I want to make a simple graph of these double values in a x-y axis in blue colour points connected by 
What's the simplest way to do it (use the x[] y[] of the main, in paint method and loop 0-100000 to paint the points and lines)?

for example i have:

```
public class sth extends JFrame{


  public sthfiltra(){

    super();
  }

  @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        for(int c=1; c<size; c++){
         g.drawLine(x[i-1],y[i-1],x[i],y[i]); 
        }
  }  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// [...]  in main i have some code. For example i want to use arrays x[i] and y[i] for visualization...

                   sth frame = new sth();
                   frame.setSize(200,200);
                   frame.setVisible(true);         

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, add your code to make it possible to help you. Here is a [helpful link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add the parameters to your paint method.

```
public void paint(Graphics g, int[] x, int[] y){
   for(int i = 1; i < x.size && i < y.size; i++){
   g.drawLine(x[i-1],y[i-1],x[i],y[i]); 
}
```

This will give you access to them.

I added the second condition to the for loop so that you won't run into array index out of bounds problems.

Comment: great my friend that's what i wanted but my arrays are double so i will Math.round() them first so I can use drawLine

Comment: Ok.  So make them double[].  Should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void paint(Graphics g, int size, double[] x, double[] y) {
  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    g.drawLine(Math.round((long) x[i - 1] * 10000), Math.round((long) y[i - 1] * 10000), Math.round((long) x[i] * 10000), Math.round((long) y[i] * 10000));
  }
}
```

Comment: you 'd rather explain why your answer solves his problem